# How should I clean ceiling texture out of a light box?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting, drywall

I had drywall contractors remove the popcorn ceiling. Everything is good, however they forgot to protect/cover one of the ceiling lights when opening it. Now there is some popcorn ceiling leftover, dust, slight moisture. I am just getting new ceiling lights. What is the proper way to clean the junction box, wire, or anything else inside there?

I'm thinking of taking a vacuum cleaner hose and cleaning the inside in a few days when moisture has dried. Anything else I should do? Are there any other actions/precautions I should take before installing new lights? It seems to be not too much, just want to be sure, before reattaching lights.

[image]

Comment: hi @crip659 I plan to vacuum in a few days, when the moisture has dried up, and will turn off circuit breaker

Comment: Presuming the floors are still covered, you could blow it out with air from a compressor or "canned air" usually used to clean computers. Let it fall to the floor, then vacuum it up from there. This might work even while it's still a little damp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess, based on experience, is that any dust and popcorn ceiling leftover is there from the initial installation. I've seen open boxes totally covered with popcorn ceiling stuff. The moisture is probably from condensation forming from the warmer air above the ceiling mixing with cooler air from below. If it will help you sleep better at night, turn off the power and brush out the inside of the box with a paint brush. If the stuff doesn't easily come off, don't try scraping it. you don't want to take a chance of damaging any insulation. Also, you could blow it out with air from a compressor or "canned air" usually used to clean computers

Comment: hi @Jack, its fresh popcorn, and dirt, I saw it literally fall/scrape into the ceiling light

Comment: I will use a paintbrush to clean it, any other solutions? thanks

Comment: @mattsmith5  Use anything you would use for dusting, not that important except for the dust getting over everything else.  Most likely you could even not dust/clean it, just put it back together, but it would bug me.

Comment: @mattsmith5  I was referring to the junction box, not the light.